# Magento: set the theme through code

Tags: magento, layout, themes

I'm using the following code to display page from Controller

```
$html = $this->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('mymodule/myblock')
        ->setTemplate('mymodule/mypage.phtml')
        ->toHtml();
echo $html;
```

Problem is I keep getting the same error

```
Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/mymodule/mypage.phtml
```

Now, the file is not located under "base" folder but under "defaul" but I'm not sure why is Magento keep searching it there.
I did the setTheme method before this display

```
Mage::getDesign()->setPackageName("default")->setTheme("default");
```

but it doesn't help, still the "base" folder is search.

Question is - what am I missing?

Comment: Pretty weird, the error message and your template's folder name are not match

Comment: aah, sorry, it is typing error, fixed it just now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's reason why you get `base` in error. Magento implements some kind of fallback mechanism while searching for your template file:

- first it searches it in current package and theme,
- then in default theme of current package,
- than in default package and default theme,
- and finally in "base",  and the last one is the one that make it into the error message.

You should carefully check the spelling of your template file name and the string inside `setTemplate` method, 99% times it's just some little typo causing this.

If it's not the case though, check what theme are you using now, maybe you're inserting your template file into wrong theme/package.

Comment: like always, it couldn't be more stupid error :-/ I spent a whole day debugging this, and all I needed is a point in the right directon :) tnx!